# Listen for Rally defect status change

Tags: events, listener, rally

I'm investigating extending the functionality of Rally for my company.

Here's what we want to do:  When a user changes the 'State' of a defect we want to run some custom code.  I'd like to attach a listener to the 'State' dropdown field so that when the state changes the listener fires some code.

Is this possible?  I've been doing some research and everything seems to indicate no.

Any suggestions or pointers or tips would be gratefully appreciated..

thanks in advance,
Brian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've set up a recurring Windows scheduled task that executes a script to look for such changes.  It's polling, but it runs very fast since it's looking for specific criteria ((state==XYZ) and (Children == nil)).

I believe with the new API I could change that to return results since the last poll time (which I would store each time I poll).

HTH

Comment: I was hoping not to have to poll, but all the research I've done suggests this is the only way.

Comment: I would love to see this functionality as well. I created a Rally Idea for it here: https://ideas.rallydev.com/ideas/D2495 feel free to vote it up.