# Call a rest api on defect change in Rally

Tags: integration, rally, user-stories, defects

Is there any way through with I can call a restfull api whenever any change is made to a defect or a user story?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't possible. You may wish to check the answer to this question:

[Listen for Rally Defect Status Change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15836966/listen-for-rally-defect-status-change)

Which has a good discussion of this topic.